# How can I use bootstrap transition .collapsing with Blazor

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, blazor, css-transitions

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) is a simple example of a collapsing element with a short transition. (The first two blue buttons.)

This is my HTML

```
<p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ToggleDropdown" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Link with href
    </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse @DropdownCssClass" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the code

```
@code {
    private bool isDropdownVisible = true;
    private string DropdownCssClass => isDropdownVisible ? "collapsing" : "show";
    private void ToggleDropdown()
    {
        isDropdownVisible = !isDropdownVisible;
    }
}
```

The div collapses but there is no transition. How can the transition be applied?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/), I applied the transition with the following code

HTML

```
<p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ToggleDropdown" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Link with href
    </a>
</p>
<div class="transition-visible @DropdownCssClass" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
    </div>
</div>
```

C#

```
@code { private bool isDropdownVisible = false;
private string DropdownCssClass => isDropdownVisible ? "show" : "transition-collapsed";
private void ToggleDropdown()
{
    isDropdownVisible = !isDropdownVisible;
} }
```

CSS

```
.transition-visible {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
    height: auto;
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transform-origin: top;
}

    .transition-visible.transition-collapsed {
        transform: scaleY(0);
    }
```

Comment: this is such an underrated answer! definitely the easiest solution I've seen

Comment: @Flippowitsch  I wanted to use this code for a accordion menue. But the div related to the button takes always a place althought it is collapsed. How should I modify the code, in order to hide the div when collapsed??

Comment: @Mdarende I tested above code [here](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/8tksm73k). Please see that the div completely vanishes. Make sure that `height: auto;` does not fill any remaining space.

Comment: The collapse is nice, but even when collapsed, the element takes up as much space as when it is expanded, kind of defeating the purpose -- any solution to that?

Comment: I found wrapping the inner `div` in `@if (isDropdownVisible) {` worked